# How to check if an id already exists in local-storage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, cart

I want to check if an id already exists or not in local-storage, because I want to display specific button if it does. How can I achieve that?

[image]

here is my code

```
export class FoodPageComponent implements OnInit {

  buttonShow = false;

  food!: Food;
  constructor(
    activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    foodService: FoodService,
    private cartService: CartService,
    private router: Router
    ) {

    activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if(params.id)
      this.food = foodService.getFoodById(params.id);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.food);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/cart-page');
  }
  

}
```

Comment: I know you can get values from local storage with this method `window.localStorage.getItem("key that You Save Your Value in localstorage").JSON.parse()`

Comment: I see your code, but I do not see any local storage usage. Please provide the piece of code that does not works and explain what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      let storageItems = localStorage.getItem('item');
      if(storageItems) {
       const items = JSON.Parse(items);
       const requiredItem = items.filter((item)=> item.id == yourId);
      if(requiredItem){
            this.buttonShow = true;
       }
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have `const id = 5` and you want to find item with `id === 5` in local storage:

```
const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"))
let exists = false

for (const item of items) {
    if (item?.food?.id === id) {
        exists = true
        break
    }
}
```

I based this code on the object structure you provided on the screenshot, so if you ever change that you will have to apply the modifications to the if condition.

Comment: thank you, this was the closest answer for my question!

Comment: @giorgimtchedlishvili If this answer is closest to the solution, consider approving the answer in order to make it easier for future users to find a solution for this or a similar question.